# Newton Raphson in Java code for beginners

Tags: java, newtons-method

My professor told us to make a program that will materialize the Newton-Raphson method in java code. The thing is that we should use beginners code for this.

*Required: The program should return the value of x1 in each repetition and we must define the accuracy of the solution.(i.e `double e=0.000005;`)

*x1 = x0 - (f(x0)/f'(x0)) x0 stands for the value we think is close to the solution.

Comment: What is beginner's code?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: *"Any ideas?"* - If you want an explanation of Newton Raphson, try Googling it.

Comment: I know what Newton's method is. I just cant materialize it into java.
By begginer's code I mean simple code.

Comment: There is no general way to get  derivative _f'_. So you need to restrict yourself to a subset of functions.

Answer (score -1):

Though it's very late, but my answer may help others who are finding implementation of Newton-Raphson method in Java.
Below is the function with the implementation.

```
public static double squareRoot (double num)    {

 double sqrt = x;

 while (sqrt * sqrt/num > 1) {
   sqrt = sqrt - ((sqrt * sqrt - num) / (2 * sqrt));

   if ((sqrt * sqrt) / num == 1)
     break;

 }
 return sqrt;
 }
```

Comment: Though there may be other better ways, but it's the simplest implementation i could think of implementing Newton Raphson in Java.